# How to send arguments to a process that started before?

Tags: c#

How do I send arguments to a process that started before?

Suppose we started process "Name.exe" before, and we know its process ID is X. In order not to open a new process, I want to send an argument to this process. How can I do this?

What is the most secure way so I will find the date received from my application, not hackers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on how this process reads these parameters (its protocol for inter-process comunications).

- If it uses named pipes - use pipes.
- If it watches for certain files - create files and write to them
- If it uses sockets - use sockets to operate
- If it listens for queue - use [MSMQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Message_Queuing) or other API for queueing

For example, you can start from *[Choosing a Transport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733769%28VS.85%29.aspx)* (MSDN).

Comment: what is most securest way for this ?

Comment: what do you mean by "secure"? If you want to send few bytes to another process then it should be able to encrypt those bytes using a paricular algorithm, if so - you just need to implement againt this contract. Moreover, security (like application logic) has nothing to do with trasnport. It doesn't realy matter whether you use RSA or 3-DES over TCP or HTTP or named pipes.

Comment: @pedram: The only data transport protocol you can pick which would be especially _insecure_ would be to write the data on a piece of paper and hand it to the hacker you're afraid of. The transport protocol isn't where your security lies.

Comment: @ Brian S : Sorry , my english is not good . 

do you want to say me all of protocols are not secure ?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above:

1. Named mutex
2. WCF service
3. Database